# facing Error with R script and library

Tags: r

I am trying to run R script but I always face this error message. Is that related to the code itself or it rather related to the installation of R and R studio.

> No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
>      Error in UseMethod("xmlRoot") :
>        no applicable method for 'xmlRoot' applied to an object of class "c('xml_document', 'xml_node')"

Answer (score -2):

To get a response object from a specified url you should use the library 'httr' , 
see here [Guide to httr package in r](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html)